# I had error "Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 86.06925048939979)" when using proj4leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I had error "Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 86.06925048939979)" when using proj4leaflet

Im using react leaflet for an interactive map. for gall-peter map projection i used proj4leaflet, while using this throwing an error "Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 86.06925048939979)" for normal projection its fine. detailed error throw is:

*> Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, 86.06925048939979)

> ```
> at new LatLng (LatLng.js:32)
> at NewClass.unproject (proj4leaflet.js:46)
> at NewClass.pointToLatLng (CRS.js:41)
> at NewClass.unproject (Map.js:1000)
> at NewClass.layerPointToLatLng (Map.js:1008)
> at NewClass._fireDOMEvent (Map.js:1436)
> at NewClass._handleDOMEvent (Map.js:1397)
> at HTMLDivElement.handler (DomEvent.js:92)*
> ```

```
crs = new L.Proj.CRS(
        'EPSG:25832',
        '+proj=cea +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +lat_ts=45.0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
        // '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'
        ,
        {
            resolutions: [
                64000,32700,16392,8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128,
                64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5
            ]
       });

    render() {                                
        return (
            <div className="map_wraper">
                {
                    this.context.sharedValues.loader ? <Loader /> : <MapContainer
                        style={this.containerStyle}
                        zoom={this.zoomLevel}                        
                        center={[10, 0]}                         
                        crs={this.crs}                                         
                    >
                        <MapConsumer>
                            {(map) => {
                                this.map = map
                                map.on('zoomend', this.zoomHandler)
                                return null
                            }}
                        </MapConsumer>

                        <GeoJSON style={this.contryStyle} data={features} onEachFeature={this.onEachCountry}  />
                    </MapContainer>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I am as curious about this as you are.  For anyone wanting to work on this, [here is a vanilla leaflet codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gall-peters-geojson-8fctw) demonstrating the issue.  I disabled the error overlay so you can actually interact with the map, but you'll see the errors in the console.  I am 100% sure this has to do with the `resolutions` option of `L.Proj.CRS`, though I'm not sure how.

Comment: might also find some clues here: [Invalid LatLng object (NaN, NaN) when trying to zoom out/in](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/issues/82)